# Switching from postgres to postgis causes address to not be resolved from host name

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to add geolocations to a postgres db and I was working w/ a postgres docker image so I decided to switch to postgis/postgis.
However when I try to connect to it with the same URI it cannot seem to resolve.  In my .env file for my docker-compose I do have the POSTGRES_SERVER tag set.

```
backend_1       | ERROR:__main__:(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

with the backend_1 being an image from https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/backend.dockerfile

Comment: Could you post the docker-compose.yaml here? Thanks Also it's best-practice to include code directly in the message, not to have links elsewhere. Mainly for the question to be useful even when the link is no longer valid.

Comment: It ended up being that I was using a newer postgis ver than my postgres image was and so it was unable to find it.